# How to find image source in jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, src, attr

I have a GridView that has a column displaying images. The problem is it is displaying the last image in all the columns so I need to set the image src in jquery but I am not sure how. I did something similar in c#:

```
 protected void gvMaintenance_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Maintenance main = (Maintenance)e.Row.DataItem;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(main.Image))
            {
                lblMainImage.Visible = false;
                imgMainImage.Visible = true;
                imgMainImage.ImageUrl = "~/MaintenanceImages/" + Company.Current.CompCode + "/" + main.Image;

                imgMainImage.Width = 200;
                imgMainImage.Height = 100;

                imgMainImage.Attributes.Add("href", "/MaintenanceImages/" + Company.Current.CompCode + "/" + main.Image);
            }
}
```

But how do I do this in jquery?

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgMainImage" />
 $("#<%= imgMainImage.ClientID %>").attr("src", "");
```

Comment: Sounds like a server side logic flaw. If you do this in jQuery what is data source for all these images?

Comment: @charlietfl all images are saved in a folder called MaintenanceImages and they all have a unique ID

Comment: that doesn't do anything to tell client side code what to set. javascript has no idea what is on your server without you providing that data

Comment: @charlietfl yes and is is my question. how do I tell javascript where the images are? Because right now it is just displaying the last image uploaded instead of the correct image

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need jQuery, if the Column has a unique path for each image then the specified Row should reflect the unique image.  The problem based on the code I see, is that your adding an `Attributes.Add` but are you certain that you've found the proper `Control`?

The other thing to be aware of, what Grid Event do you have the image being built in?

Those are a couple of suggestions, without more code we won't be able to help though.

Comment: What do you mean by control? I've added all the code to display the image in my question

Comment: Are you using an `Image Control` or a `img runat="server"`

Comment: I'm using  `runat="server"`

Answer (score 0):

The code in the gvMaintenance_RowDataBound needed to be removed and I was able to link the images in jquery using this:

```
 $("#<%= imgMainImage.ClientID %>").attr("src", "<%= "/MaintenanceImages/" + Company.Current.CompCode + "/" %>" + $(sender).children().eq(14).html());
```